# Lazy Vertical Grid workaround in compose

Tags: android, grid, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm trying to implement Grid Layout with 2 columns using Compose, but LazyVertical Grid does not work for me. I searched for some workarounds to fulfill the task, but nothing was rendered on a screen. Any ideas?

```
 val state = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        state = state,
        content = {
            items(bookList.books){
                bookList.books.map {
                    BookUI(book = it, onClick = {})
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

I tried using LazyVerticalGrid this way, but it does not render a list, while LazyColumn renders it

Comment: Kindly explain what you are doing with a minimum reproducible example and why "LazyVertical Grid does not work for me".

Comment: Post some code if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: ` val state = rememberLazyListState()
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            state = state,
            content = {
                items(bookList.books){
                    bookList.books.map {
                        BookUI(book = it, onClick = {})
                    }
                }
            }
        )` this snippet renders nothing, while LazyColumn renders a list

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `map` when using `items`.

Change

```
items(bookList.books){
    bookList.books.map {
        BookUI(book = it, onClick = {})
    }
}
```

to

```
items(bookList.books){ book ->
    BookUI(book = it, onClick = {})        
}
```

Don't forget to import,

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

Comment: Still does not render the items, I think it is not stable yet and does not work properly

Answer (score 2):

Implementation has changed since the time your question was created, so the following code snipped should work in your case:

```
val state = rememberLazyGridState()
LazyVerticalGrid(
    state = state,
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
) {
    items(bookList.books) { books ->
       BookUI(book = it, onClick = {})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyGrid(items: List<String>) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(count = 2)
    ) {
        items(items) { text ->
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }
}
```

Few things you should pay attention to:

- the `items(*) {}` function need to be imported from `androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items`
- You added `@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)`
- `rememberLazyListState()` is actually a default param so no need to add it.

For the above example you can use something like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Content() {
    MyGrid(
        items = listOf(
            "Item A",
            "Item B",
            "Item C",
            "Item D",
            "Item E",
            "Item F"
        )
    )
}
```

And you will get this:

[image: example]